# Allow single quote in Email Regx validation

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, email-validation

I want to allow a single quote in email while doing the javascript email validation.

I have used the following code but it's working as expected.

```
 var pattern = new RegExp(/^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/);
 return pattern.test(emailAddress);
```

Following emails it should return as valid

```
 zoe.o’hara@test.com 
 natalie.o'sullivan@test.co.in
```

Comment: Email validation is actually something regex is not that good at, this link has a more robust version you could try =>  https://emailregex.com/  the perl version looks terrifying..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I validate an email address using a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-can-i-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just need to add `'` and `’` to the first character class

Changing:
`[a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]` to `[a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.'’]`

Fixed:

```
var pattern = new RegExp(/^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.'’]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$/);
return pattern.test(emailAddress);
```

Do be aware of Keith's comment. [There is more info in a question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/how-can-i-validate-an-email-address-in-javascript).

Comment: it's not working

Comment: @Rober https://jsfiddle.net/85nwsh29/